# using doctrine2 sluggable extension with silex

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex

I'm running into a strange problem trying to use the doctrine2 extension sluggable and timestampable in silex.

First of all I've succeded to use doctrine2 with silex following this guide:

http://martinsikora.com/silex-doctrine2-orm

After that, using this other guide, I've add sluggable and timestampable listener to my entity manager:

http://silex-doctrine-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/doctrine.html

Now in my entity I've got this problem:

if I use something like that:

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```

doctrine2 don't recognize my entity, I need to use:

`@Entity` instead of `@ORM\Entity`

But if I use `@ORM\Entity` gedmo seems to work but he said me that he can't find the sluggable or the timestampable field (modified, created etc..) and if I run orm:generate-entities doctrine2 don't find my entity.

If I use `@Entity` instead of `@ORM\Entity` everithing work fine, but when I add the gedmo annotation like:

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

@Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
```

The Entity gave me errors about the normal annotation like `@Column(type="datetime")`

I think the only way is to use the prefix `@ORM\` like every example I find on internet, but with this prefix `orm:generate-entities` stop finding my entity.

In symfony2 I've not this problem, I use `@ORM\` prefix and doctrine2 extension sluggable and timestampable like a charm, I run into this problem using Silex, that have no native support to doctrine2 orm, only dbal, so I use the following provider to use the nutwerk-orm-extension

If you guys have some idea, please share with me.

Answer (score 4):

Did you added the Gedmo namespace in composer?

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Gedmo": "vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib'"
        },
}
```

I use this extension with Silex:

https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider

I add the provider and the subscriber:

```
//Setting Doctrine ORM
$app->register(new Dflydev\Silex\Provider\DoctrineOrm\DoctrineOrmServiceProvider, array(
    "orm.proxies_dir" => $app['db.orm.proxies_dir'],
    "orm.em.options" => array(
        "mappings" => array(
            array(
                "type" => "annotation",
                "namespace" => "Entity",
                "path" => 'my_path',
            )
        ),
    ),
));

//Setting Doctrine2 extensions

$timestampableListener = new \Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener();
$app['db.event_manager']->addEventSubscriber($timestampableListener);
```

It works for me but I have to add these "uses" in my entities:

```
namespace Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue;

/**
 * EntityPages
 *
 * @Table(name="pages")
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Entity\Repository\PagesRepository")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class EntityPages
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
```

Comment: Very helpful thank you. I also found out that using traits are easier `    use TimestampableEntity;` without need for `* @HasLifecycleCallbacks()` also for multiple DBs I needed `$app['dbs.event_manager']['default']->addEventSubscriber(new \Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener());`